# Importing WSDL in a WSDL

Tags: integration, wsdl

I have two WSDL files .

The first one imports the second one using import tag.
How to replace the second one within the first one ?
Do we need to replace along with the  tag ?

Answer (score 1):

I've built an independent (free) tool that will automate this for you. You can get it from [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (Disclosure: That is my current employer).

It should automatically handle the imports for you assuming it can access them. There are more details in my [Dreamforce Presentation](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html).